# Using oauth2 in php for accessing twitter, moving it to Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, twitter, localhost, twitter-oauth

I found the code below on the net ([here](http://foren.activevb.de/forum/webentwicklung/thread-265/beitrag-266/Twitter-OAuth-using-PHP-without/)) and tried implementing it on Google App Engine.

It works perfectly when i ran it on localhost, but when i deployed it to App Enginge i get nothing in `$encodedData`.

```
$authContext = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode(($consumerKey).':'.($consumerSecret)) . "\r\n".
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8\r\n".
                "Content-Length: 29\r\n".
                "\r\n".
                "grant_type=client_credentials",
    ),
));
$authResponse = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token", false, $authContext);
$decodedAuth = json_decode($authResponse, true);
$bearerToken = $decodedAuth["access_token"];

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer " . $bearerToken . "\r\n".
                     "\r\n".
                     "grant_type=client_credentials",
    ),
));

$encodedData = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=samkiesupdates&count='."100", false, $context);
```

Anyone who knows what i need to alter in the code to have it work on the Google App Engine server?
Maybe it says in the replies to the forum post i linked above, but sadly i don't speak german so i can't tell.

Comment: You're putting the POST body into the header field of the context options, which seems pretty wrong to me.

Comment: There could be a lot of things wrong, i'm using someone else's code, and i'm new to using http requests, trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting the post body in the 'content' field of the [http context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) options, and no need to specify the content length.

```
$authContext = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode(($consumerKey).':'.($consumerSecret))."\r\n".
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8\r\n",
        'content' => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
    ),
));
```

Do that same for the other http request you make.

Comment: I tried that, and it produced this error on GAE (worked fine on localhost):

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=samkiesupdates&count=100): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in main.php on line 35

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it didn't even work on localhost so it's not working at all.

Comment: Or nevermind, if i only changed the first request the code works. However when i attempt to do the same changes to the second request i produces the error above. I'll try deploying it to GAE to see if this is enough.
**EDIT** It did work with changing only the first request, thank you Stuart!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear this stuff up, and to make this whole question / answer more visible. Here is the working code example:

```
  <?php

    $consumerKey    = <YOUR CONSUMER KEY>;

    $consumerSecret = <YOUR CONSUMER SECRET>;

    $authContext = stream_context_create(array(

      'http' => array(

        'method'  => 'POST',

        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode(($consumerKey).':'.($consumerSecret)) . "\r\n".

          "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8\r\n",

        'content' => "grant_type=client_credentials"

        ),

    ));

    $authResponse = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token", false, $authContext);

    $decodedAuth = json_decode($authResponse, true);

    $bearerToken = $decodedAuth["access_token"];

    $context = stream_context_create(array(

      'http' => array(

          'method'  => 'GET',

          'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer " . $bearerToken . "\r\n",

          'content' => "grant_type=client_credentials"

        ),

    ));

    $encodedData = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=<YOUR TWEET ID>', false, $context);


    $result = json_decode($encodedData);
```

Thanks for the help,

Nick